# Can we get Adviza back?

Tags: feature-request

As an example of Natural Language Processing, I've been looking at Eliza, and, in mentioning that, I talked about its fork for Stack Exchange, Adviza (AKA "Chat With An Expert"). **Would it be possible to get access to Adviza for the purpose of demoing a modern use of Eliza-style NLP?** This is of academic teaching interest.

I'm sure the code's still around somewhere, so I hope fulfilling this request wouldn't be too big an issue.

Comment: I want Doctor Sbaitso (sp?)

Comment: PARITY ERR ... 21303 @AndrewBarber

Comment: Are you asking for the code, or are you asking for this thing to be made a permanent part of Stack Overflow? It doesn't really make sense to host a gimmicky April fools joke for the rest of the site's lifespan just so *you* can show it to people.

Comment: YES YES DR SBAITSO

Comment: If the question is about getting the code (for demo), then this is not a dupe.

Comment: I'm asking if I can use Adviza to show my Artificial Intelligence that the Eliza system is still being used, today. It also doubles as an aide to help them understand that there are more uses than purely professional

Comment: @Anna reopening this hint you consider such an option?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not really (as in, not a hint). This isn't up to me in any way and I've no idea what's involved. However, the duplicate was an odd choice, so... reopened.

Answer (score 5):

Every copy of GNU Emacs has a complete implementation of Eliza, just do m-X doctor. The source is right there.

You might also want to keep in mind that the author of Eliza did not see it as a good example of anything. The basic outline is in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA; I heard it in person.

To make this stronger: there is no such thing as 'modern use of Eliza-style NLP.' No respectable person in the field of NLP would consider Eliza to be an example of a modern NLP approach, and an April Fool's joke is not a practical use.

Comment: This won't help, as I wish to show that the system is still being used. Displaying archaic code that happens to still exist won't do this, but showing a still-working system will.

Comment: people use the doctor in gnu emacs every day, while the Adviza think was just a prank for a brief interval. That's not a 'working system'.

Comment: @Supuhstar: I'm entertained that you believe *Emacs* to be archaic...a gvim user perhaps?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I meant the Eliza code